# Swift ui xcode NSPasteboard empty

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, clipboard, nspasteboard

[image]

I have the following code at the beginning of the program, when it starts I need to see if there is any copied text.

But if I start the program and no text has been copied at the moment, I get the following error.

How can I solve the problem?

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

```swift
init() {
        let paste = NSPasteboard.general.string(forType: .string)!
...
}
```

Comment: If you want to find out whether or not you can return a value, why are you force-unwrapping it?

Comment: Besides, that's probably not the right way to do it.  Try using the data property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
init() {
    if let paste = NSPasteboard.general.string(forType: .string) {
        // do something with paste
    } else {
        // do something when paste is nil
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if let _ = NSPasteboard.general.data(forType: .string) {
    print("You have data")
} else {
    print("Oops, you don't.")
}
```